# Correct item selected upon user pressing enter for a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a WPF with a custom combo box that, as the user types, filters the remaining list for words that CONTAIN (not just start with) the user input. Now i would like to press enter, and the first item in the drop down be the selecteditem.

Here is the before :

[image]

Desired behavior: when i press enter from here, DHC becomes the SelectedItem.

What actually happens:

[image]

HEI becomes the selected answer, (probably because it was the only node that started with "HE".

In order to fix this, i attempted to overload the keypress function by including this in the xaml:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown" >
      <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding KeyPress}"
         PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

which routes to this in the code:

```
private void OnDownPress(KeyEventArgs e)
{
   var key = e.Key.ToString().ToLower();
   switch (key)
     {
        case "up":
           break;
        case "down"
           break;
        case "return":
           SelectedNode = NodeTokenList[0];
           UserInput = NodeTokenList[0].FullNodeName;
           break;
     }
 }
```

Now I tried setting a break point on the return part of the switch statement, I have to press enter 3 times before the switch gets triggered. And even then the text box does not reflect the desired behavior

Comment: you can probably bind the selected item and set it to be first item in the filtered list

Comment: hmm doing something along those lines seems to work. If you want to answer it, i will accept. Follow up question though, when i attempt to scroll through the drop down, it changes the value in the textbox, which then filters the list for only those that match the string, leaving only the item in the text box as a possible answer...what would be a way so that i can navigate using the arrow buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the Selected Item in your Model and everytime the filter changes you set the SelectedItem to the first item in the filtered list

> what would be a way so that i can navigate using the arrow buttons

if WPF combo box does not support arrow navigation by default you can do something with Command Binding.

First you bind the `SelectedIndex` property, then the down command will just set `SelectedItem = filteredList[SelectedIndex + 1]` (with boundary check ofc)

But I remember keyboard navigation should be included with the default `Combobox` though